# In elastic beanstalk, how do I run a command before the container is launched?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the a single container docker version of Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a ruby on rails application (my docker is pre-built).
The docker image specifies a CMD of "rails server".

I would like to issue "rake db:migrate" just before the "rails server" is run. Is there a way to do it using elastic beanstalk configuration or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you replace the `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` with a script where you run that inside the running docker container (runs each time you start the docker container), or you add this to `.ebextensions/00-my-tasks.config`:

```
container_commands:
  00-my-task:
    command: rake db:migrate
```

Then it runs in the elastic-beanstalk container/virtual machine, but outside of docker container.

Comment: running a script is what resolved it for me. the extension solution won't work as the rake need to run inside the container.

Comment: If you need to run rake inside the container you could specify the command as a docker run command - e.g. docker run <myimage> rake db:migrate - but you probably want this to run only once per deployment so generally ECS is better for more complex deployment scenarios as it allows you to run single-shot "tasks" before/after/during running your long-running "services"

Comment: Some documentation says to use `container_commands:`, while other docs say to use `commands:`, not sure which is correct.

Comment: @spuder `container_commands: ` run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed. and The `commands:` run before the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted.